# Variable explorer changes data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, spyder

I am using Spyder 3.2.7 and am using the Variable explorer. I have written a customized class based on dictionary

```
class DateScheme(dict):
    """
    Container object for Date Schemes
    Dictionary-like object that exposes its keys as attributes.
    """

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # other keys omitted

    def __dir__(self):
        return self.keys()

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)

DateSchemeInstance = DateScheme("NewName")
```

When I run the above code I see `DateSchemeInstance` in the variable explorer and the type of the variable is `DateScheme` (as expected). When I double click on it I see its description but already the Window title is `DateSchemeInstance - Dictionary (1 elements)`, and indeed the type of the `DateSchemeInstance` is actually changed to dictionary, making the methods of the original class unavailable.

Do I miss something or is this a bug? Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This certainly looks like a bug. Please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues), posting the above code so we can investigate what's happening in this case.

Comment: ok, have done so, for follow-up see https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6936